# Equivalent definition of "totally boundedness"

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A metric space (X, d) is said to be totally bounded (or precompact) if, for every $\epsilon > 0,$ the space X can be covered by a ﬁnite family
of open balls of radius $\epsilon $.

Another way of saying this is: A metric space (X, d) is totally bounded if, for
every $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists a ﬁnite subset A ⊆ X such that d(x, A) < $\epsilon $ for all x ∈ X.

So my question is : Can we say that a metric space is totally bounded if and only if it has a finite dense subset? 
(I guess we cannot because I have never heard of it. But according to the meaning of dense subset, I cannot find where the problem is.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The following answers are both perfect. I tried to mark them both but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"But according to the meaning of dense subset, I cannot find where the problem is."

The problem is that a dense subset is "good" for all choices of $\epsilon$, whereas in your case, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a certain finite subset that will do, but this particular finite subset may not do for all smaller choices of $\epsilon$, and in fact, will never do, because it is finite.

Comment: Brief and clear. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Pearl -- you are most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot. If $F$ is a finite subset of a metric space $X$, then $\overline F=F$ and therefore $F$ is dense if and only if $F=X$.

If $X$ is totally bounded, then there is a finite set $F$ such that $X=\bigcup_{x\in F}B_1(x)$. And there is *another* set $F^\star$ such that $X=\bigcup_{x\in F^\star}B_{1/2}(x)$. It doesn't have to be the *same* set. And it usually isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very helpful. It helped me better understand the concept. But I finally chose the other one, because my confusion mainly resulted from the second paragraph of the question. And the other answer focused on the "difference" of subsets in the second paragraph. Your answer is really helpful so I feel so so sorry that I did not mark it as the best. Love you.

Comment: The choice if an accepted answer is a strictly personal one, but I'm glad that you explained why you accepted the other one. And, of course, I'm also glad I could help.